While upgrading jdk8 to jdk17 I am facing jacoco error
Updated my jdk from jdk8 to jdk17.
Junits are failing with the below error -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:84)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy26.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:52)
... 59 more
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException:
Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.
It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
Java               : 17
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 17.0.11+7-LTS-207
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 17.0.11+7-LTS-207
JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:234)
... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/bytebuddy/agent/ByteBuddyAgent
at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:117)
... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 66 more

Please Note -  I am updating this in my already written code which was earlier on JDK 8 and now I am moving the code to JDK17 . Junits earlier used was Junit4 + PowerMocking was happening in the code. I have learned that power Mockito is not compatible with JDK17 so I changed my Junits to Junit5 (jupiter) Still Facing this error.
If required , I can share my build.grdale file as well.

Check out PowerMockRule with JDK 11 and Mockmaker exception - Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker
